# FindBugs command line: how to specify the project to be analyzed?

Tags: java, findbugs

I tried to run [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) in command line and had troubles when specifying the project to be analyzed. I understand FindBugs works on bytecode (.jar, .class), so I wrote a HelloWorld program and made sure that it had some messy code that would be detected by FindBugs.

Then I tried:

```
java -jar D:/findbugs-2.0.3/lib/findbugs.jar -project HelloWorld/bin
```

which threw an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't read project from HelloWorld/bin
              at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.Project.readProject(Project.java:774)
```

I also tried .class and .jar files, but nothing showed up:

```
java -jar D:/findbugs-2.0.3/lib/findbugs.jar -project HelloWorld/bin/Main.class
java -jar D:/findbugs-2.0.3/lib/findbugs.jar -project HelloWorld.jar
```

I checked the FindBugs manual about the command line option "-project", it says

> The project file you specify should be one that was created using the GUI interface. It will typically end in the extension .fb or .fbp

I don't understand this. Does it mean that some pre-processing is required and FindBugs cannot check arbitrary .jar or .class or project directly? How can I get this .fb or .fbp extension?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The procedure is described [on the FindBugs website](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/gui.html):

- Make sure you [download](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/downloads.html) the FindBugs distribution which includes the GUI (called *Swing interface*).
- Extract your downloaded ZIP and add its *bin* folder to your PATH.
- Type `findbugs` to open the GUI, then click *New Project*
- In the dialog:

  - Enter a project name, say `HelloWorld`.
  - Where it says *Classpath for analysis*, give it the Jar with your .class files or a directory where the .class files are (such as `build/classes/main` or whatever; the package structure must start in this directory).
  - Where it says *Auxiliary classpath*, list any libraries required to load your classes.
  - *Source directories* works just like *Classpath for analysis*, but for .java files. FindBugs uses this to show you where in the code your issues are.
  - You can select `(cloud disabled)` as bug store.
- Click **Analyze**.
- Now you can save the project configuration as a .fbp project file.

Next time, you can start the analysis by running

```
java -jar D:/findbugs-2.0.3/lib/findbugs.jar -project HelloWorld.fbp
```

If you don't want to or cannot use the GUI, you can get the text-only version by adding the `-textui` option as first option after findbugs.jar. Output formats and behavior are configured via [additional command line options](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/running.html#d0e852).

However, most people use FindBugs integrated with their IDEs, or as part of a build process. Neither use case should require the GUI or command line versions. Take a look at the plugins for your IDE, it may save you a lot of time and they are really easy to use.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed instructions! I followed every step but when I clicked "Analyze", FindBugs GUI pops up an "Analysis failed" window, saying "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:35328". Do you have any idea what caused this exception? Thanks!

Comment: Googling your error message leads me to assume that you are using Java 8? There seems to be a FindBugs bug with Java 8. Try compiling with Java 7.