# Project creation from CLI

Tags: jenkins, command-line-interface, findbugs

Is it possible to create a project file .fbp only from findbugs CLI?

I can only find [this documentation](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/gui.html) to create projects:

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24157777/findbugs-command-line-how-to-specify-the-project-to-be-analyzed) the suggested answer also implies to use graphical interface.

But it is strange to me that we won't be able to create projects from command line. Is there any trick to get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to generate via CLI. And it's needless because `.fbp` file is only for GUI application.

If you need a way to configure findbugs analysis for the build on Jenkins, then it is not this file but [Maven plugin](https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs-maven-plugin/) or [Gradle plugin](https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs-gradle-plugin/).

BTW [FindBugs is not maintained any more](https://mailman.cs.umd.edu/pipermail/findbugs-discuss/2017-September/004383.html), so I recommend you to use [SpotBugs](https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) instead.